# how can I create ibook shelves like-style user interface for android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I just want to ask about how to create a UI and add a functionality to be ibook-shleves like letting user choose the book from the shelves

[image]

I wish that there is a library that help me do that on android or any idea how to start doing that

thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an open source project that does something  similar: http://code.google.com/p/shelves/
You can download the project and inspect the code.

The idea behind this should be a ListView with a custom adapter, I believe.